# Have Flask-AutoIndex serve the children of the app directory but not "/" itself

Tags: python, flask, flask-autoindex

I have a flask application and I want to serve files in the subdirectories of the folder where my flask application resides.  I tried doing this with `Flask-AutoIndex` like so:

```
AutoIndex(app, browse_root=os.path.curdir )

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html');
```

This serves my static content out of `/css` and `/js` nicely, but I can't get `/` to route to the `index` function. Instead, the AutoIndex routes `/` and displays all the files, including my application source code file.  I tried setting `add_url_rules` to `False` which allowed `index` to route `/` but`/css` and `/js` are no longer served.

How can I have all subdirectories of my application be autoindexed but still allow the application to handle `/`?